# Failed eclipse update when trying to install eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

When trying to install eclipse using the eclipse new software feature, I get this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Maven SCM handler for Subclipse (Optional) 0.9.8.200905041414 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.subclipse.feature.feature.group 0.9.8.200905041414)
Missing requirement: Maven SCM handler for Subclipse (Optional) 0.9.8.200905041414 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.subclipse.feature.feature.group 0.9.8.200905041414) requires 'org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I am new to eclipse, so I would appreciate any tips on how to get going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the [m2eclipse SCM handler](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Integration+with+Subclipse) does not find or is not compatible with the Subclipse you are trying to install.
In any case, you need to install or complete the installation of subclipse first, *before* installing m2eclipse.

See the relevant [Subclipse update site](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Installation+Requirements#InstallationRequirements-Subclipse), and *then* try to complete the m2eclipse installation.

See [a full Subclipse, then m2eclipse installation process there](http://web.archive.org/web/20110108113222/http://www.lafabrick.com/blog/2009/06/11/1174-flashbuildereclipse-installation-guide-subclipse-pdt-wtp-and-maven/).

Comment: I don't even use SVN, so can I just skip this step somehow?

Comment: so I removed the subeclipse options, and now its complaining about   Software being installed: Maven Integration for AJDT (Optional) 0.9.8.200905041414 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.ajdt.feature.feature.group 0.9.8.200905041414)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for AJDT (Optional) 0.9.8.200905041414 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.ajdt.feature.feature.group 0.9.8.200905041414) requires 'org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 1.5.0' but it could not be found

Comment: @Blankman you can try and install plugin AJDT (Optional)AJDT update site for Eclipse 3.5 http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/35/update

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the [Pulse explorer](http://www.poweredbypulse.com/) in where you can find plugins for eclipse .. such as subversive, maven .. etc. I just installed it the other day its great, you don't even have to have eclipse.. it creates an instance of eclipse with all the features you choose. Fabulous tool if you ask me.