# Error when installing plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I try to install a plugin in Eclipse I get these error messages

> Registry event dispatcher

```
Error notifying registry change listener.
Error notifying registry change listener.
Invalid registry object
Error notifying registry change listener.
Invalid registry object
Error notifying registry change listener.
Invalid registry object
Error notifying registry change listener.
Invalid registry object
Error notifying registry change listener.
Invalid registry object
```

Has someone an idea what the cause of this problem could be? Thanks

Edit:

I see the Eclipse .log file has also a lot of new stack traces

The first one is

```
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=nl_NL
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 2 2010-05-06 21:04:31.236
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.equinox.registry".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.InvalidRegistryObjectException: Invalid registry object
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TemporaryObjectManager.getObject(TemporaryObjectManager.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.BaseExtensionPointHandle.getExtensionPoint(BaseExtensionPointHandle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.BaseExtensionPointHandle.getContributor(BaseExtensionPointHandle.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.BaseExtensionPointHandle.getNamespace(BaseExtensionPointHandle.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PopupMenuExtender.registryChanged(PopupMenuExtender.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry$2.run(ExtensionRegistry.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.processChangeEvent(ExtensionRegistry.java:919)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.spi.RegistryStrategy.processChangeEvent(RegistryStrategy.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.ExtensionEventDispatcherJob.run(ExtensionEventDispatcherJob.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Edit2:

When I restart Eclipse I get a "install connectors" window, but when I select a connector and click on "Finish" nothing happens and there appears an "Unhandled event loop exception" in the Eclipse log

Edit3:

I tried Subclipse instead of Subversive but that gives these errors

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libapr-1 in java.library.path
no libapriconv-1 in java.library.path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Core\bin\libeay32.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Core\bin\ssleay32.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
no libaprutil-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_subr-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_delta-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_diff-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_wc-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_fs-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_repos-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_ra-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_client-1 in java.library.path
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = C:\Windows\system32;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Core\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Core\oic;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin
```

Is there a possibility that the installed Eclipse version conflicts with another installed Eclipse version or with Zend Studio?

Comment: What plugin are you installing? And how are you doing this?

Comment: I'm trying to install Subversive via the "Install new software" in the Help menu

Answer (score 7):

It's problem with x64 Java.

With x64 java you need to use JavaHL with x64 support

This is official FAQ
http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-0ae839721445e3f59d10a128ec9439d4f4988d5f

I have same installation and it works after steps from FAQ

Edit: You may also need to edit your PATH variable (in Windows at least) to include the `bin` folder from the [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) install that is recommended in the [subclipse FAQ](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-0ae839721445e3f59d10a128ec9439d4f4988d5f) listed above.

Comment: in addition the above I also had to remove csvn from my PATH

Answer (score 3):

If you are installing Subclipse plugin for SVN in eclipse on windows7 64 bit. Make sure you do not install JavaHL as part of the plugin install options. You need to separately install SilkSVN install outside the eclipse. Steps are here,
First install SilkSVN, than install Subclipse plugin install withouth JavaHL plugin checked.

Answer (score 2):

For Kirk Woll:

Modify your `Path` in `Environment variables`

Change `C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\` into `C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin`

maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install SlikSvn http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download
2. Change system variables path: `C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\` to `C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin`

Answer (score 1):

Did you observe that on a fresh installation of Eclipse?
And in the case of your instance of Eclipse, did you try to relaunch iot a *second* time? (and still see errors?)

Because when several plugins are already there, [this thread mentions](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.equinox/msg05785.html) (for `AJDT` but that can be applied to other plugins as well):

> The error means that somebody holds on to the handles to the extension registry objects that no longer exists.
>
> Most likely `AJDT` (or one of the bundles it depends on) maintains persistent cache of registry objects, such as extensions or extension points.
> When a bundle is updated, behind the scene the "old" version of the bundle is uninstalled, removing all its registry elements, and when the new version of the bundle is installed, adding new registry element.
> If a bundle cached handles for extensions/extension points and did not react to the registry events, it ends up with invalid handles.

Comment: yes, when I try to relaunch Eclipse a second time I see again the "Install connectors" window which doesn't work.

It is a fresh installation (Eclipse folder and workspace folder removed). But when I start the new Eclipse installation still my projects are visible, so maybe there is a way for a complete fresh installation?

Comment: @Derk: yes, there is a way: just unzip a full eclipse installation archive somewhere ;)

Comment: I tried it with unzipping the full eclipse archive on a different drive with no sucess :( exactly the same errors

Comment: @Derk: what version of Eclipse are you using? Did you try Subclipse instead of Subversive? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232645/failed-eclipse-update-when-trying-to-install-eclipse/2232702#2232702)

Comment: I'm using the Helios 3.6 version 64 bit for Windows. I tried Subclipse but that was giving the same messages during the installation (Error notifying registry change listener.). I will past the errors it shows when rebooting in the opening post

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, running eclipse 64 bit on windows 7 64 bit, trying to use subclipse and this is how I fixed it:

1. I have installed eclipse Helios 64 bit.
2. I have installed jdk 1.6 64 bit.
3. I have installed subclipse.
4. I have installed JavaHL (Slik subversion) 64 bit.
5. I had to make sure eclipse uses the 64 bit version Java when launching (this can be verified when looking at the java.library.path property in `eclipse->help->about eclipse->installation details->configuration`. Make sure it shows also the path to your 64 bit JDK - if not, change the relevant system environment variable from your windows control panel->system and restart eclipse with the -clean variable).